# POST and Download a file using curl

Tags: curl, cmd, http-post

I am trying to `POST` using `curl` inside windows command prompt, in an attempt to download a file and save it. Here is my curl command:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -o report.xlsx -d "{\"TimePeriod\":\"Jan 2016\", \"ShowHistory\": false, \"Scenario\":\"Base\" }" http://localhost:12222/MyApp/api
```

The command runs but the report file is of 0 bytes (empty). If I do the same post using postman, I can get the proper file.

Any clues as to why the file has no contents?

I have extensively followed [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request) but to no avail.

Comment: Can you remove the SPACE character between `Jan` and `2016`?

Comment: @lit, why would that matter? It is just a value in the JSON object

Comment: I try `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -o report.xlsx -d "{\"TimePeriod\":\"Jan 2016\", \"ShowHistory\": false, \"Scenario\":\"Base\" }" https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts` and it works fine (on WSL). Can you check requests with wireshark?